# Windows 8 Store App and WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

If I try to add a service reference to my blank windows 8 app, I've got following two warnings/errors.

[image: TransportSecurityBindingElement]

The service is a wcf service with a ServiceName.svc file, i've seen some services wit a ServiceName.asmx. Is this the cause? Does I need a service with an *.asmx file?

I'm really confused because there is too much and wirde stuff on the internet for this topic.
Also confusing is, it says that System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement is not supported, but I never used this. Not in web.config or in the code as service configuration.

Here my service configuration in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
  <httpRuntime/>
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
</diagnostics>
<client/>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="basicHttpBehavior" name="e3kConnector.E3KConnectorService">
    <endpoint 
      address="mex" 
      binding="mexHttpBinding" 
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint 
      address="" 
      binding="wsHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
      name="wsHttpEndpoint" 
      bindingName="" 
      contract="Service.MyService" />
    <endpoint 
      address="Soap" 
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" 
      name="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingName=""
      contract="Service.MyService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50282/Service.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="e3kConnector.App_Data.Security.CustomUserNameValidator,e3kConnector"/>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="tempCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="e3kConnector.App_Data.Security.AuthorizationPolicy, e3kConnector"/>
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

As test I added this [tempConverter](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL), but this works. (Yes I know it's an asmx file.)
I know also the difference between svc and asmx, but thats why I'm confused. Both supports SOAP, so I still don't get it why it won't work. Maybe it's very simple?

If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: Forget about asmx - that is .net 1.1 and 2.0 services and is not WCF. Anything 3.0 and above should be using svc

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I'm using .net 4.5 now is the question how can i get it working :D

Comment: So do you get the problem when you try to add the service reference? Does the service run fine?

Comment: Yes, but only with win8 store apps. A WinForm application works without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Windows Store client apps support only a [small subset of WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx).

Try this slimmed down config on your service (removed binding wsHttp, behavior and binding configs):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  ....
  <services>
    <service name="e3kConnector.E3KConnectorService">
      <endpoint
        address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <endpoint
        address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        name="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="Service.MyService" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50282/Service.svc" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  ....
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Yep this works. Thanks. So then I need to create a second service for my other clients which use the wsHttpBinding?

Comment: Well you could try adding the wsHttp endpoint back in, but give it an address qualifier like "wshttp" or something and it may work. The problem before may have been that the wshttp endpoint was the same URI as your base address and the basic endpoint was called "soap". If you reversed this your metro app could still work and your other consumers can go to the wshttp. It's worth a try but it may be that the extra stuff in the wsdl will prevent metro from consuming.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try this on monday when I'm back in the office :)